# Concatenate 2 columns after checking a condition

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm trying to concatenate these 2 columns "pv.name package_version_name" and "sf_li.sf_lma_version_number_c" im trying to join it with the if statement below.
[Package_version_name] ([Version_Number])
Example output: Chicago Update 2 (14.4.2)
ill throw another example, Version Number: (13.0.10); package_version_name: Chicago; the output/new column (version release): Chicago (13.0.10). In some cases package_version_name already has both the fields concatenated example package_version_name: Brooklyn (9.5.14), so we can just output this alone in the new column (version release) : Brooklyn (9.5.14) without adding version number, as it is already there.

```
sf_li.sf_lma_version_number_c AS version_number,
pv.name package_version_name,
IF( CONTAINS(pv.Name , ")"), pv.Name, pv.Name + "(" + sf_li.sf_lma_version_number_c + ")"),
FROM "prod"."salesforce"."sf_lma_license_c" sf_li
    left join "prod"."salesforce"."sf_lma_package_version_c" pv
        on sf_li.sf_lma_package_version_c=pv.id
```

Comment: what sql are you using

Comment: also can you reformat your questions what does this mean:  `If the package_version_name doesnt already have the version number in ( ) some of the rows in version name already has version number, if it doesnt have, im trying to join it with the if statement below.`

Comment: So, ill throw an example, Version Number: (13.0.10); package_version_name: Chicago; the output/new column (version release): Chicago (13.0.10). In some cases package_version_name already has both the fields concatenated example package_version_name: Brooklyn (9.5.14), so we can just output this alone in the new column (version release) : Brooklyn (9.5.14) without adding version number, as it is already there. Also im using dbt it is very similar to mysql

Comment: i mean check your grammar or reword

Comment: check the solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**code to run:**

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' OR package_version_name NOT LIKE '%)%'  
     THEN   CONCAT(        
                     CONCAT(cast(package_version_name as char(200)),
                            cast('(' as char (200))) 
                            , 
                     CONCAT(cast(version_number as char(200)),
                            cast(')' as char(200)))        
                  ) 
     ELSE 
        package_version_name   as final_version_field
 FROM 
     [TABLE NAME] / from {{ref('[TABLE NAME]')}}
```

**Extra condition:**

You can also add another condition i.e:

```
WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' AND IS_VARCHAR(package_version_name) = 'True'
```

This will also check that you don't have brackets i.e `(` and `)` and the value is of type `varchar`. I have used `IS_VARCHAR` as i am using snowflake you can find the one related to your sql

Comment: thanks a ton! appreciate it. is there a way to maintain the same edit? Right now my output is like Chicago14.0.4 instead of Chicago (14.0.4) @trillion

Comment: is there a way to maintain the same edit? Right now my output is like Chicago14.0.4 instead of Chicago (14.0.4) @trillion

Comment: which sql are you using ? snowflake ?

Comment: getting a error "column "(" does not exist in sf_li, pv" im using fivetran and dbt

Comment: which sql are you using

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh try again i added single comma's

Comment: dbt is not a sql its a data modelling tool, your fivetran is just a connector tool for etl. You must be using a specific SQL like MySQL, Snowflake, Redshift or Biquery, SQL server

Comment: im bad with these terminologies, yes we are using redshift

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh also i updated your question tag with redshift

Comment: ```                                                                                                                             -- CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',skuid_version_number,')') else package_version_name end skuid_release,
       CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' AND VARCHAR(package_version_name) = 'True',                                                     
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: it is actually not, saying "function concat(character varying, "unknown", character varying, "unknown") does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: but the first code you tried was working before ?

Comment: you are not supposed to combine the second code just use the first one as i added in the comment above

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh did you try Just this : `select CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%'     THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',version_number,')') else package_version_name as final_version_field  FROM [TABLE NAME]` ?  this should work

Comment: also add the correct table name in the code above

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh did you try the code ?

Comment: the first code you sent without the brackets formatting works fine, but the next ones dont @trillion

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh can you show me the erro please. Just run this: `select  CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%'
    THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',version_number,')') else package_version_name as final_version_field FROM [TABLE NAME]` Whe nyou run this what error do you get ?

Comment: it is not accepting '(' , ')' it says its unkown or character varrying

Comment: "function concat(character varying, "unknown", character varying, "unknown") does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts." this is the error

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh please paste the exact code you are running on your end

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh run the code : `select CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(TO_CHAR(package_version_name), '(',TO_CHAR(version_number),')') else package_version_name as final_version_field FROM [TABLE NAME] / from {{ref('[TABLE NAME]')}}`

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh run the code in the comment above i have adjusted

Comment: Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
function to_char(character varying) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. this is what says in your adjusted code in the above comment @trillion

Comment: the idea here is to convert all cocat fields to string, why the `to_concat` is not working with redshift ? I am using this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_CHAR.html

Comment: I think the '(' ')' are the problem here, those are not passing as any variable i guess @trillion

Comment: syntax error at or near "')'"
LINE 22: ...ion_name), '(', cast(version_number as char(100)) ')' ) ELSE... @trillion with the last code

Comment: Try to run this one, there were too many brackets in the previous code: `select CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT( cast(package_version_name as char(200)), '(',cast(version_number as char(200)),')') else package_version_name as final_version_field FROM [TABLE NAME] / from {{ref('[TABLE NAME]')}}`

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh did you check the code above ?

Comment: this should work, it works on my end. It is weird that redshift `to_char () ` is not working, neverthless I am trying the `cast` function from this link: [cast function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html) . The problem is not the `(` or `)` they are added as strings.

Comment: Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
function concat(character, "unknown", character, "unknown") does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. I think it says unknown for the '(' ')' because that is what the error is saying @trillion

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh That is so weird it works on my end using snowflake, i guess you will have to live without it. is that fine ?

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh or lets cast the '(' as well and then try

Comment: `select CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT( cast(package_version_name as char(200)), cast('(' as char (20)),cast(version_number as char(200)),cast(')' as char(200)) else package_version_name as final_version_field FROM [TABLE NAME] / from {{ref('[TABLE NAME]')}}`

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh maybe try this

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh if this doesn't work then it's really weird atleast you have the version joined together

Comment: it says concat cannot have 4 values passing in it, it is takking the brackets as values, thats what the case was also last time, i guess, may be we can try to concat first and format in next step, and i really appreciate your help, thanks for taking this time to help. @trillion

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh yes i just read the documentation you CAN only concat two strings we have 4  more than that. Try this:  `select CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT
LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%'

THEN 

concat(
       CONCAT(cast(package_version_name as char(200)),cast('(' as char (20))) ,
       
       CONCAT(cast(version_number as char(200)),cast(')' as char(200))) 
      )
else package_version_name 

as final_version_field FROM [TABLE NAME] / from {{ref('[TABLE NAME]')}}`

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh would be great if you can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh any update on the last code ?

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh hey any uppdate ?

Comment: it worked perfect now!! really appreciate your help, I did accept your answer, but unfortanately cannot upvote as I dont have enough reputation

Comment: @KarthikcharanSuresh no worries, i am glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct sf_li.id license_id,
        sf_li.created_date as license_created_date,
       sf_li.name                               AS license_name,
       sf_li.sf_lma_install_date_c              AS install_date,
       sf_li.sf_lma_subscriber_org_id_c org_id,
       sf_li.sf_lma_org_type_c                  AS org_type,
       sf_li.sf_lma_subscriber_org_is_sandbox_c AS sandbox_org,
       sf_li.sf_lma_status_c                    AS status,
       sf_li.sf_lma_version_number_c            AS skuid_version_number,
       sf_li.sf_lma_expiration_c expiration_date,
       sf_li.sf_lma_license_type_c license_type,
       sf_li.sf_lma_package_license_id_c package_license_id,
       sf_li.sf_lma_package_version_c package_version_id,
       pv.sf_lma_package_c package_id,
       pv.name package_version_name,
       pv.sf_lma_release_date_c package_release_date,
       pv.release_number_c package_release_number,
       CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, skuid_version_number) else package_version_name end skuid_release,
       --CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',skuid_version_number,')') else package_version_name end skuid_release,
      -- CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' AND VARCHAR(package_version_name) = 'True',
      -- CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',version_number,')') else package_version_name as final_version_field
       CASE WHEN package_version_name NOT LIKE '%(%' or package_version_name not like '%)%' THEN CONCAT(package_version_name, '(',skuid_version_number,')') else package_version_name end skuid_release, 
       sf_li.sf_lma_seats_c subscription_count,
       sf_li.sf_lma_used_licenses_c subscriptions_used,
       case when subscription_count > 0 then subscriptions_used::decimal(10,2)/subscription_count::decimal(10,2) else -1::decimal(10,2) end utilization,
       case when sf_li.sf_lma_org_type_c LIKE 'Developer%' then TRUE::boolean else FALSE::boolean end is_developer,
       l.id lead_id,
       l.email lead_email,
       l.has_opted_out_of_email lead_email_opt_out,
       l.title,
       l.industry,
       l.behavior_score_c behavior_score,
       l.demographic_score_c demographic_score,
       l.webinar_score_c webinar_score,
       coalesce(l.behavior_score_c,0) + coalesce(l.demographic_score_c,0) + coalesce(l.webinar_score_c,0) combined_lead_score,
       c.id contact_id,
       c.email contact_email,
       c.has_opted_out_of_email contact_email_opt_out,
       sf_li.installation_category_c            AS installation_category,
       case when sf_li.sf_lma_subscriber_org_is_sandbox_c = TRUE then 'Sandbox' when is_developer = TRUE then 'Developer' else 'Production' end org_category,
       l.datahugapps_ma_c                       AS matched_account,
       case when not c.id is null then 'Contact' when not l.id is null then 'Lead' else 'Unknown' end installer_type,
       coalesce(c.id,l.id) lead_or_contact_id,
       coalesce(c.name,l.name) lead_or_contact_name,
       coalesce(c.owner_id,l.owner_id) lead_or_contact_owner_id,
       coalesce(sf_c_o.name,sf_c_o_g.developer_name,sf_l_o.name,sf_l_o_g.developer_name) lead_or_contact_owner_name,
       coalesce(c.account_id,l.datahugapps_ma_c) account_id,
       coalesce(sf_c_a.name,sf_l_a.name) account_name,
       coalesce(sf_c_a.vertical_c,sf_l_a.vertical_c) account_vertical,
       coalesce(sf_c_a.type,sf_l_a.type) account_type,
       coalesce(sf_c_a.segment, sf_l_a.segment) account_segment,
       coalesce(sf_c_a.owner_id,sf_l_a.owner_id) account_owner_id,
       coalesce(sf_c_a_o.name, sf_l_a_o.name) account_owner_name
FROM {{source('salesforce','license')}} sf_li
    left join {{source('salesforce','package_version')}} pv
        on sf_li.sf_lma_package_version_c=pv.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','package')}} pk
        on pv.sf_lma_package_c=pk.id
    LEFT JOIN {{source('salesforce','contact')}} c
        ON sf_li.sf_lma_contact_c=c.id
    LEFT JOIN {{source('salesforce','lead')}} l
        ON sf_li.sf_lma_lead_c=l.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','account')}} sf_c_a -- salesforce contact account
        on c.account_id=sf_c_a.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','account')}} sf_l_a -- salesforce lead account
        on l.datahugapps_ma_c=sf_l_a.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','user')}} sf_c_a_o -- salesforce contact account owner
        on sf_c_a.owner_id=sf_c_a_o.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','user')}} sf_l_a_o -- salesforce lead account owner
        on sf_l_a.owner_id=sf_l_a_o.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','user')}} sf_c_o -- salesforce contact owner
        on c.owner_id=sf_c_o.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','user')}} sf_l_o -- salesforce lead owner
        on c.owner_id=sf_l_o.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','group')}} sf_l_o_g -- salesforce lead owner group
        on c.owner_id=sf_l_o_g.id
    left join {{source('salesforce','group')}} sf_c_o_g -- salesforce contact owner group
        on c.owner_id=sf_c_o_g.id
    where not sf_li.is_deleted
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.